# Activity java not found

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, path, manifest

I am building my own cordova plugin for android. However, when I am calling an activity implementation in cordova plugin from my cordova app, it appears that my activity java file is not detected by my cordova app.

While the logcat stated,

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {my.app.path/my.plugin.path.SampleActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Oddly, the path of my plugin is concatenated to the path of my app. I am pretty sure that I've declared my activity in AndroidManifest.xml within my cordova plugin.

Snippet (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<activity android:name="my.plugin.path.SampleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Snippet (plugin.xml)

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="app/src/main/application">
    <activity android:name="my.plugin.path.SampleActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation">
    </activity>
</config-file>
```

Snippet (PluginInterface.java)

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext mCallbackContext) throws JSONException {

    this.mCallbackContext = mCallbackContext;

    Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);

    return true;
}
```

Appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issues lies within plugin.xml. By changing from

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="app/src/main/application">
  <activity android:name="my.plugin.path.SampleActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:configChanges="orientation">
  </activity>
</config-file>
```

to

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
  <activity android:name="my.plugin.path.SampleActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:configChanges="orientation">
  </activity>
</config-file>
```

solves the problem entirely.